# Commands in the "system" block works in console but NOT inside application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano, bundler, resque

It has been 12 hours since I've been trying to solve this problem... Here it is:

Inside my controller, I have a method like this:

> ```
> def restart_workers
>       system("cd /var/www/sts/current && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=#{Rails.env.to_s} resque:restart_workers")
>
>       redirect_to presets_path, :notice=>"Worker'lar yeniden yuklendi. Yeniden acilmalari birkac saniye surebilir."
>   end
> ```

ALL I want is to use that rake task to restart my Resque workers... That task works perfectly during applications initilalization.

This line runs perfectly when I try it in my console:

```
system("cd /var/www/sts/current && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=#{Rails.env.to_s} resque:restart_workers")
```

But when I call this method through my application, I see the error below in my `unicorn.log`:

```
/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:16:in `build': /var/www/sts/releases/20130422190645/Gemfile not found (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:148:in `definition'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
```

I'm really stucked.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

FYI, I'm using:
RVM, Capistrano, Unicorn, nginx

Comment: how's this related to `system`? seems to me Bundler's warning you that you're missing a Gemfile.

Comment: Probably I'm missing something big but I really can't figure it up. Strange part is, there is no path such as "/var/www/sts/releases/20130422190645" I don't understand why it looks inside releases of a few day ago

Comment: well this is not a matter. you are using Capistrano and may be "/var/www/sts/current" is pointed to "/var/www/sts/releases/20130422190645"

Comment: Nope @bilash.saha, here is my `ls -lah` results:
`lrwxrwxrwx.  1 deployer deployer   36 Apr 25 06:36 current -> /var/www/sts/releases/20130424193523`

Comment: When is the controller action being called? During deployment? Afterwards?

Comment: Hi @iltempo, I'm triggering that action by clicking a button.

Comment: Somehow current appears still being linked against to old release, even if it isn't. Don't know why. Can you try `cd #{Rails.root}` instead? Should be better anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks God I've found an answer to my question in this blog post:
http://blog.willj.net/2011/08/02/fixing-the-gemfile-not-found-bundlergemfilenotfound-error/